# Run-in section in memoir

Tags: memoir, section-titles

I'm trying to achieve run-in sections with `memoir`. The "section title" within the book I'm typesetting is actually the first word of a sentence, just in italic, but it goes into the TOC and is "technically" a section.

I've tried

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\title{memoir sec}

\begin{document}
\setsecnumdepth{part}
\setsecheadstyle{\itshape}
\setbeforesecskip{-\baselineskip}
\setlength{\aftersecskip}{-\fontdimen2\font plus \fontdimen3\font minus \fontdimen4\font}

\section{Test section title}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

And it works properly, so far this testing document is concerned:

[image]

But in the real document - which is quite complex and I cannot share, unfortunately - there is still a sort of extra space:

[image]

I am grateful for any clue (e.g. helping understanding how `memoir` manages the skips, telling where to look for debugging...)

---

EDIT: with `\showoutput`, in the real document just after the last letter of the section title I have

```
.....\glue(\spaceskip) 2.19 plus 1.095 minus 0.73
.....\glue(\spaceskip) 2.19 plus 1.095 minus 0.73
.....\glue(\spaceskip) 2.19 plus 1.095 minus 0.73
.....\write4{\protect \BOOKMARK [1][-]{section*.1}{\376\377\000F\000r\000a\000n\000c\000i\000s\000c\000o}{chapter.1}% 2}
.....\write1{\@writefile{toc}{\protect \contentsline {section}{Francisco}{\thepage }{section*.1}\protected@file@percent }}
.....\glue 2.39806 plus -1.19902 minus -0.79935
```

whereas in the test document (which gives the desired output) there is only

```
.....\write4{\protect \BOOKMARK [1][-]{section*.1}{\376\377\000T\000e\000s\000t\000\040\000s\000e\000c\000t\000i\000o\000n\000\040\000t\000i\000t\000l\000e}{}% 1}
.....\write1{\@writefile{toc}{\protect \contentsline {section}{Test section title}{\thepage }{section*.1}\protected@file@percent }}
.....\glue 3.33 plus -1.665 minus -1.11
```

Any guess about what can be the reason?

Comment: Try looking at pdf memoir.cls

Comment: Thanks @PeterWilson

Comment: In fact, I've found out that the issue came from spaces within a `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands` command. 
Shall I delete the whole question? Or close it? Or what else?